# Cmake Error make: *** Makefile: Resource deadlock avoided. Stop

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, vscode-devcontainer

```
make[2]: *** CMakeFiles/exec.dir/compiler_depend.make: Resource deadlock　avoided. Stop. 
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/exec.dir/all] Error 2 
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

This error happens so often when I type `make` command and then I type `cmake ..` to initialize cmake. That the only way I know to solve the error.
It may be caused by docker container, or compiler option (openMP).

My environment is
M2 Macbook Pro
MacOS Sonoma

Docker Desktop 4.25.1
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
cmake 3.22.1
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0

I'm passing `-fopenmp` option to gcc.

CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
# Set the version of CMake required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

# Set the project name and the language used
project(ARModel CXX)

# Create an executable and specify the source files
add_executable(exec predict.cpp AR.cpp)

# Include path
target_include_directories(exec PUBLIC /usr/include/python3.10)

# Specify the library directory
link_directories(/usr/lib/python3.10)

# Create a shared library
add_library(cnpy SHARED "cnpy/cnpy.cpp")

# Link the libraries
target_link_libraries(exec PUBLIC python3.10 cnpy z)

# Set the linker library search policy
if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)

# Set compiler options
set(CMAKE_NO_CACHE TRUE)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++20 -O3 -fopenmp -mtune=native -march=native -I/usr/include/python3.10")
```

In Makefile

```
# All Build rule for target.
CMakeFiles/exec.dir/all: CMakeFiles/cnpy.dir/all
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/exec.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/exec.dir/depend  
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/exec.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/exec.dir/build
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --progress-dir="/workspaces/AR model/cpp/build/CMakeFiles" --progress-num=3,4,5,6 "Built target exec"
.PHONY : CMakeFiles/exec.dir/all
```

Comment: Does **every line** in your code **essential** for reproducing a problem? Try to remove a line and check whether the error message remains when you configure and build the project. The whole error message smells like a problem with your environment and it could be absolutely unrelated with CMake.

Comment: This error also happens in git.
This may be an issue stemming from the devcontainer. (competition between the guest os and the host.)

Comment: Do not post multiline error messages via *comments*. Instead [edit] the **question post** and make sure it contains all relevant information.

Comment: Side note: Forget about `make`, it's incredibly slow. Use the cmake `ninja` generator instead and then build your code with `ninja` instead - it's much more efficient.

Comment: I looked through compiler_depend.make. The dependencies between source files are specified there.
The possible cause of this error could be the inability of CMake to reference this file for some reason.

Comment: @bike "The possible cause of this error could be the inability of CMake to reference this file for some reason" - That's just guessing.

Comment: This doesn’t help solve the problem per se, but I have just started seeing the same build error in my previously stable build now that I upgraded to macOS Sonoma. I think it might be to do with that. It’s a bit of a coincidence. Never saw it before and nothing much else has changed on our build system. HTH